# Running php and composer under OSX results in timed out error

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I'm using Homebrew to run php and composer under OSX. To develop my php applications I use Valet. Everytime I want to require a package or update my installed packages I get this error:

> The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out Retrying with
>   degraded mode, check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode
>   for more info

I've tried several solutions (allowing `"secure-http":false`, changing the repository-url, etc.).

But nothing seems to work global. Using the secure-http flag works sometimes, but the script takes way too long to finish (e.g. installing a new laravel project).

Is there a way to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by activated IPv6 in my networksettings for my Wi-Fi connection.

Here is the [Link to the composer-website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-).

Short way to handle it:

1. deactivate IPv6 for your used connection `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi`
2. run your composer-commands
3. reactivate IPv6 for your used connection `networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi`

If you don't need IPv6 on your machine, you can leave it disabled.

Comment: Also solved the problem for me. Thanks for sharing the details :)